# Problem creating longtable. ! Misplaced \noalign error

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow

Im having troubles when using he longtable package. I have already search for like 3 hours on several posts and nothing has worked. I upload (hope to do it right) the table.

```
\usepackage{longtable,lscape}
\usepackage{multirow,multicol}
\begin{center}
\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|X|X|X|}%[H]

\caption{3D printing materials}\label{tabla:Materials}

\hline

\textbf{Printing Technology} & \textbf{Material} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}
{\textbf{Material properties}} & \textbf{3D printing problems} \\ \hline
\multirow{21}{*}{FDM\footnote{All data is against XZ axis.}} 

& \multirow{7}{*}{PC-ABS\footnote{All data obtained from 
\cite{materials:pcabs_stratasys}}} & Tensile Modulus & 1810MPa & \multirow{21}
{*}{blablabla} \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Tensile Strength & 34MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Elongation to Break & 5\% &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Modulus & 1740MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Strength & 59MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Melting Point & N/A\footnote{Due to amorphous nature, material does not 
display a melting point.} & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Dielectric Constant\footnote{Also known as Relative Permittivity.} & 2.78 
- 2.83 &  \\ 
\cline{2-4}
&\multirow{7}{*}{ABS\footnote{All data obtained from \cite{materials:abs_stratasys}}} & Tensile Modulus & 2230MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Tensile Strength & 32MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Elongation to Break & 7\% &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Modulus & 2060MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Strength & 60MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Melting Point & N/A & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Dielectric Constant & 2.6 - 2.86 & \\ \cline{2-4}

& \multirow{7}{*}{Nylon 12\footnote{All data obtained from \cite{materials:nylon_stratasys}}} & Tensile Modulus & 1282MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Tensile Strength & 46MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Elongation to Break & 30\% &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Modulus & 1276 &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Strength & 67MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Melting Point & 178$^{\circ}$C &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Dielectric Constant & N/A &  \\ \cline{2-4}
\hline 

\multirow{14}{*}{SLA\footnote{All data obtained from 
\cite{materials:3dsystems_materials}}} & 

\multirow{7}{*}{VisiJet\textregistered\ Black} & Tensile Modulus & 2150MPa & 
\multirow{14}{*}{blablabla} \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Tensile Strength & 45MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Elongation to Break & 5\% & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Modulus & 2350 & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Strength & 76Pa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Melting Point & N/A & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Dielectric Constant & N/A & \\ \cline{2-4}

\multirow{7}{*}{VisiJet\textregistered\ Tough} & Tensile Modulus & 1890MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Tensile Strength & 41MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Elongation to Break & 18\% & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Modulus & 1850 & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Strength & 62MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Melting Point & NA & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Dielectric Constant & N/A & \\ \cline{2-4}
\hline  

\multirow{14}{*}{SLS} & 
\multirow{7}{*}{Alumide\textregistered \footnote{All data obtained from \cite{materials:shapeways_alumide}}} & Tensile Modulus & 3800MPa & \multirow{14}{*}{blablabla} \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Tensile Strength & 48MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Elongation to Break & 4\% &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Modulus & 3600 & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Strength & 72MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Melting Point & 172-180$^{\circ}$C & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Dielectric Constant & 13 ${\pm}$ 1.5 &  \\ \cline{2-4}


& \multirow{7}{*}{Nylon (PA2200) \footnote{All data obtained from \cite{materials:shapeways_pa2200}}} & Tensile Modulus & 1700MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Tensile Strength & 48MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4} 
& & Elongation to Break & 24\% &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Modulus & 1500 &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Strength & 58MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Melting Point & 172-180$^{\circ}$C &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Dielectric Constant & NA &  \\ \cline{2-4}
\hline 

%\end{tabularx}

\end{longtable}
\normalsize
\end{center}
```

I would really appreciate the help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! There's a few issues with your code that I can see. (i) you're missing `\documentclass{...}` right at the very beginning. (ii) Don't use `\begin{center}...\end{center}`. `\begin{table}\centering...\end{table}` will suffice. Also ensure your caption is placed within the table environment, i.e. after `\begin{table}`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your code suffers from a number of severe errors, any of which will crash compilations. In the following, I've tried to fix up what I perceive the ones that actually cause crashes. Naturally, I'm not in a position to judge the contents.

Do compare the old and new code to discover all the changes I made. Among the most important ones are

- The revised code uses `table` and `tabular` environments instead of `longtable` and `tabularx` environments. (Aside: You can't pack a `tabularx` environment inside a `longtable` environment.)
- The `\footnote` command doesn't work properly if it's placed inside a `\multirow` statement. I've therefore loaded the `threeparttable` package and split the `\footnote` instructions into pairs of `\tnote` and `\item` instructions. Separately, since vertical space is at a premium, I've loaded the `threeparttable` package with the option `para`, so that multiple short footnotes can be typeset on a single line.
- Don't overlay `\cline{2.4}` and `\hline` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
% set page parameters:
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont
\caption{3D printing materials}\label{tabla:Materials}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{2.25cm}| c| *{2}{l|}
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.25cm}| }
\hline
\textbf{Printing Technology} &
\textbf{Material} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Material properties}} & 
\textbf{3D printing problems} \\
\hline

\multirow{21}{*}{FDM\tnote{1}}
& \multirow{7}{*}{PC-ABS\tnote{2}}
  & Tensile Modulus & 1810MPa & 
  \multirow{21}{*}{blablabla} \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Tensile Strength & 34MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Elongation to Break & 5\% &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Modulus & 1740MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Strength & 59MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Melting Point & N/A\tnote{3} & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Dielectric Constant\tnote{4} & 2.78--2.83 &  \\
\cline{2-4}

&\multirow{7}{*}{ABS\tnote{5}} 
  & Tensile Modulus & 2230MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Tensile Strength & 32MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Elongation to Break & 7\% &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Modulus & 2060MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Strength & 60MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Melting Point & N/A & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Dielectric Constant & 2.6--2.86 & \\ 
\cline{2-4}

& \multirow{7}{*}{Nylon 12\tnote{6}} 
  & Tensile Modulus & 1282MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Tensile Strength & 46MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Elongation to Break & 30\% &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Modulus & 1276 &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Strength & 67MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Melting Point & 178$^{\circ}$C &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Dielectric Constant & N/A &  \\ 
%%%\cline{2-4}
\hline

\multirow{14}{*}{SLA\tnote{7}} 
& \multirow{7}{*}{VisiJet\textsuperscript{\textregistered} Black} 
  & Tensile Modulus & 2150MPa &
  \multirow{14}{*}{blablabla} \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Tensile Strength & 45MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Elongation to Break & 5\% & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Modulus & 2350 & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Strength & 76Pa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Melting Point & N/A & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Dielectric Constant & N/A & \\ 
\cline{2-4}

& \multirow{7}{*}{VisiJet\textsuperscript{\textregistered} Tough}
  & Tensile Modulus & 1890MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Tensile Strength & 41MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Elongation to Break & 18\% & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Modulus & 1850 & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Strength & 62MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Melting Point & NA & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Dielectric Constant & N/A & \\ 
%%%\cline{2-4}
\hline

\multirow{14}{*}{SLS} 
& \multirow{7}{*}{Alumide\textsuperscript{\textregistered} \tnote{8}} 
  & Tensile Modulus & 3800MPa & 
  \multirow{14}{*}{blablabla} \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Tensile Strength & 48MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Elongation to Break & 4\% &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Modulus & 3600 & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Strength & 72MPa & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Melting Point & 172--180$^{\circ}$C & \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Dielectric Constant & $13 \pm 1.5$ &  \\ 
\cline{2-4}

& \multirow{7}{*}{Nylon (PA2200) \tnote{9}} 
  & Tensile Modulus & 1700MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Tensile Strength & 48MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Elongation to Break & 24\% &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Modulus & 1500 &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Flexural Strength & 58MPa &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Melting Point & 172--180$^{\circ}$C &  \\ \cline{3-4}
& & Dielectric Constant & NA &  \\ 
%%%\cline{2-4}
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\raggedright\footnotesize
\item[1] All data is against XZ axis.
\item[2] All data obtained from \cite{materials:pcabs_stratasys}
\item[3] Due to amorphous nature, material does not display a melting point.
\item[4] Also known as Relative Permittivity.
\item[5] All data obtained from \cite{materials:abs_stratasys}
\item[6] All data obtained from \cite{materials:nylon_stratasys}
\item[7] All data obtained from \cite{materials:3dsystems_materials}
\item[8] All data obtained from \cite{materials:shapeways_alumide}
\item[9] All data obtained from \cite{materials:shapeways_pa2200}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```